# How to test live site on local IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, iis-6, localhost

I have a site that should be on real hosting, but I want to test it on local pc.
So,

1. I copied it into directory C:\MySite
2. in IIS6 I have created new site "mysite.com", set up the path to
   C:\MySite
3. in hosts file I added line: 127.0.0.1 mysite.com

When I try to open http://mysite.com or http://mysite.com/Default.aspx in my browser it throws 404 "The page cannot be found".

How to resolve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you setup IIS to use the correct .NET version that the site is written in? http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1f74eac5-9005-4f91-9137-f63b73eefde8.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Sounds like the ASP.NET ISAPI is disabled or not registered.

Comment: Yes, I set up ASP.NET version 4.0, that my site uses

Comment: vcsjones - Sounds like the ASP.NET ISAPI is disabled or not registered.  - Yes, you are completely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the right version of asp.net installed? Did you make sure the "execute asp applications" (or however it's called) checkbox was checked?

Comment: (Can't comment on your thing yet)... did you set up ASP.NET before or after you set up IIS?  If before, then you'll have to register ASP.NET to answer requests with aspnet_regiis.   <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=VS.100).aspx>

Answer (score 0):

In IIS manager did you make that folder an asp.net application and picked the framework version you are targeting? Check [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1d1c9a73-b4c5-4cfb-ad69-b77fa2e17e19.mspx?mfr=true) and [this](http://www.enewsletterpro.com/support/appstartpoint.asp) for more information on it.